# Grails 2.2.2 No value specified for parameter 2

Tags: hibernate, grails

Here is my problem.

I have 3 domains class

**Contributor.groovy**

```
class Contributor extends User{
    static hasMany = [instruments:Instrument]
}
```

**Project.groovy**

```java
class Project {
    static hasMany = [instruments: Instrument]
    static belongsTo = [contributor: Contributor]
}
```

**Instrument.groovy**

```java
class Instrument {
    static belongsTo = [Contributor, Project]
    static hasMany = [projects: Project, contributors: Contributor]
}
```

Then I have a **Service** with a function to find all projects that contains a list of instruments

```java
def getProjectsByInstruments(){
        def result = null
        def instrument = Instrument.findByName("Accordion");
        def instrumentList = new HashSet<Instrument>();
        instrumentList.add(instrument)
        result = Project.findByInstruments(instrumentList)
        return result
}
```

When I execute the function I get this error message:

```
2013-12-09 11:45:44,711 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO  soundshare.ProjectController  - Entering Action /project/by_instrument
2013-12-09 11:45:44,712 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO  soundshare.ProjectController  - Instrument : ACCORDION
2013-12-09 11:45:44,714 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select this_.id as id17_0_, this_.version as version17_0_, this_.name as name17_0_ from instrument this_ where this_.name=? limit ?
Hibernate: select this_.id as id17_0_, this_.version as version17_0_, this_.name as name17_0_ from instrument this_ where this_.name=? limit ?
2013-12-09 11:45:44,717 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - Accordion
2013-12-09 11:45:44,717 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicExtractor  - found [1] as column [id17_0_]
2013-12-09 11:45:44,727 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicExtractor  - found [1] as column [version17_0_]
2013-12-09 11:45:44,727 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] TRACE sql.BasicExtractor  - found [Accordion] as column [name17_0_]
2013-12-09 11:45:44,729 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select this_.id as id31_0_, this_.version as version31_0_, this_.contributor_id as contribu3_31_0_, this_.description as descript4_31_0_, this_.musical_style_id as musical5_31_0_, this_.name as name31_0_, this_.open_to_public as open7_31_0_, this_.poster_url as poster8_31_0_ from project this_ where this_.id=? limit ?
Hibernate: select this_.id as id31_0_, this_.version as version31_0_, this_.contributor_id as contribu3_31_0_, this_.description as descript4_31_0_, this_.musical_style_id as musical5_31_0_, this_.name as name31_0_, this_.open_to_public as open7_31_0_, this_.poster_url as poster8_31_0_ from project this_ where this_.id=? limit ?
| Error 2013-12-09 11:45:44,729 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - No value specified for parameter 2
| Error 2013-12-09 11:45:44,742 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /project/by_instrument - parameters:
instrument: accordion
No value specified for parameter 2. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No value specified for parameter 2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Post the whole stack trace it will be easy to locate the problem

Comment: Just edited my post with full stacktrace

Comment: I'm wracking my brain trying to remember how this is a valid dynamic finder: Project.findByInstruments(instrumentList) because I don't believe it is.

Comment: Why not ? `class Project hasMany = [instruments: Instrument]``

Comment: could you explain ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
Project .withCriteria {
  instruments{
    eq('name', 'Accordion')
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, could you explain why mine doesn't ? Thanks anyway

Comment: After trying this, my error now reads: "No value specified for parameter 1".  Can someone please explain this error and how it is supposed to be solved?